# jquery check value present in an object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if a value is present inside an array of object

```
function hasProperties(id){
    jQuery(JSON.parse(jQuery("#PropertiesField").html())).each(function () {
        if(id== jQuery(this)[0].properties.id) {
            console.log((id== jQuery(this)[0].properties.id));
            return "Present";
        }
    })
};
var something = hasProperties("someid");
```

the above snippet returns `undefined` for `something`, but also true is logged in console. why is it not returning `present` when condition satisfies, what is the mistake that I have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function provided in the each method is an anonymous inner function. Therefore, nothing is returned outside of each() context. To tackle this you can do something like,

```
function getProperty(id){
var result;
    $('your element').each(function(){
        //If your condition is true
        result=expectedValue
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think you actually want to parse `#PropertyField` html as JSON and then want to make its jQuery object. Do a check on it.
2. Instead of doing `jQuery(this)[0].properties.id`, just do `this.id`, that is not a right syntax.

Comment: thanks, now i am using this.properties.id, but the problem persists
it is logging "true" in console, but the value is not getting assigned to the var

Comment: @vignesh just do `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the return i had is for the `.each()`. I added a return outside the foreach function and it works now

```
function hasProperties(id){
var found =false;
    jQuery(JSON.parse(jQuery("#PropertiesField").html())).each(function () {
        if(id== jQuery(this)[0].properties.id) {
            console.log((id== jQuery(this)[0].properties.id));
            found= true;
            return;
        }
    })
return found;
};
var something = hasProperties("someid");
```